# Magento2 upgrade script removes module out of modules array

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

Ive got my module config

app/code/SET/HelloWorld/etc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">     
    <router id="standard">     
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">     
            <module name="SET_HelloWorld" />     
        </route>     
    </router>     
</config>
```

And added it in etc/config.php:

```
'SET_HelloWorld' => 1,
```

But after running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` The key in te config.php array is gone.

Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that i missed the Registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SET_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

If the module is not registered, magento delete it automatically out of the config.php array.

This registration is added recently and not found in a loth of tutorials online